# Getting 500 Internal Server Error while sending the confirmation email to the registered user using Flask

Tags: flask, eve, flask-mail

I want to send the email confirmation link after entering the registration details to the registered user,
when I entered the user registration details then URL corresponding signup() method,

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app1 = Flask(__name__)

app1.config.update(
    DEBUG=True,
    #EMAIL SETTINGS
    MAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com',
    MAIL_PORT=465,
    MAIL_USE_SSL=True,
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'surya123@gmail.com',
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'sss'
)

mail=Mail(app1)


@app.route('/auth/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    accounts = app.data.driver.db['people']
    user = {
        'email' :request.json['email'],
        'password' :generate_password_hash(request.json['password'])
    }
    accounts.insert(user)
    token = create_token(user)
    msg = Message('Confirmation Link From WEBER',
              sender='surya123@gmail.com',
              recipients=[user.email]
    )
    msg.html = '<div>this is test html</div>'
    mail.send(msg)
    return jsonify(token=token)
```

Here is I am Getting 500 Internal server Error, Please resolve this,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you importing Eve anywhere in your code so when you run this line:

```
accounts = app.data.driver.db['people']
```

unless `app` is initialized somewhere else, you are going to get an error. Also make sure you set `DEBUG = True` on `app` settings, so you can get a full stacktrace when it fails.